# SQl Constraints Check integrity of data (the last name has to be unambiguous/unique) return number of data sets that harm constraint

Tags: sql

I have the following Query to write:
-- Suppose there is the following constraint: "The last name must be unique". Create a Query, -- which checks whether this condition is met. The request is intended to determine a number that indicates how many data sets would have to be deleted for the condition to be met.

The way I interpret this request is as following:

If I have the data

| last_name |
| --- |
| Betty |
| Betty |
| Betty |
| Tommy |
| Bob |

The rows for 2 Betty's would have to be deleted and the returned number would be 2

How would I go about accomplishing this?

EDIT: I used the following code to achieve the desired result:

```
SELECT (COUNT(last_name) - COUNT(DISTINCT last_name)) AS to_delete

FROM employees;
```

which returns 2, however the checker from my professor returns that I used last_name too often, is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Given that the 3 values you've listed are unique, why do you think any of them would need to be deleted?

Comment: Edited the post for clarity I meant 3 instances of the same name and two of those would have to be deleted so the returned value would be 2 and only one name would be left in the table

Comment: OK - that makes more sense. Hint: you would need to use a GROUP BY and HAVING count > 1. Try this and if you still can't get it to work then update your question with the SQL that you do manage to write and ask a specific question about whatever issue you are still facing

Comment: You could do COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(last_name) - at least if last_name is not null. But I'd say your query is even clearer. (And I don''t like constraint dependent queries, a query should return the same even if constraints are added or removed.)

Answer (score 0):

The query below will give the number of duplicate last names: -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS dele_count
FROM (
  SELECT last_name
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY last_name
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS dup;
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, perhaps better performing (depending on dbms and index):

```
select sum(cnt)
from
(
  select count(*) - 1 as cnt
  from employees
  group by last_name
) dt
```